# How to invoke Java function multiple times from inline Javascript Expression using ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I am evaluating an inline Javascript Expression using Java 8's `ScriptEngine`.

Example Expression

```
(_tranxAmount > 100) && (profile.received('daily', 'avg', false) < 100)
```

Where `profile` is a global scope bind Java class object and `received()` is its local function. I successfully evaluated this expression using `scriptingEngine.eval(script)` and it is calling `profile.received('daily', 'avg', false)` I mean to say `functionsManager.received('daily', 'avg', false)` as well.

The Scripting engine failed to evaluate JavaScript expression if it contains more than one Java function. In that case, only the first Java function gest called. How to resolve this issue?

For example

```
(_tranxAmount > 100) && (profile.received('daily', 'avg', false) < 100) && (profile.sent('monthly', 'count', false) < 5)
```

Script Engine:

```
private static ScriptEngine scriptingEngine;
```

Inside constructor of main class

```
scriptingEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
scriptingEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put(PROFILING_FUNCTIONS_PREFIX, functionsManager);
```

Evaluating Expression

```
Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings(customMapOfVaraibles);
CompiledScript compiled = ((Compilable) scriptingEngine).compile(" (_tranxAmount > 100) && (profile.received('daily', 'avg', false) < 100) && (profile.sent('monthly', 'count', false) < 5)");
compiled .eval(bindings)
```

`functionsManager`'s methods look like this

```
public BigDecimal received(String intervalType, String statisticsType, boolean considerTranxType)
            throws InvalidRequirementsException {
   //Do calculations
   return calculatedValue;
}

public BigDecimal sent(String intervalType, String statisticsType, boolean considerTranxType)
            throws InvalidRequirementsException {
   //Do calculations
   return calculatedValue;
}
```

Comment: Is the result of `profile.received` less than 100? `&&` is short-circuiting, so it won't execute `profile.sent(..)` unless the previous condition was true.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks dude, you're right. should I delete this question? after changing 100 to 90, now its invoking both functions

Comment: You can, but you don't need to. I closed it as a duplicate, so the question could potentially serve as a signpost.